# Copy HTML code but without javascript changes

Tags: html, firebug

In Firebug there is very useful "Copy HTML" option in HTML Tab. But that copied HTML code also includes javascript changes like for example added new classes on document.ready (jQuery) event. I would like to copy raw HTML code like in "View source" option (it is every browser) without and javascript changes. Yes, I can use "View source" option but code in there is very scattered and it is very hard to copy one big HTML node not losing closing tag and in firebug with fold blessing I can match folded HTML node, right click and select "Copy HTML".

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the SAME page from the server using an AJAX call, assign it to a variable. Done.

Comment: Yes. I can also make script fetching that node, but in that case (your way) using Firebug is pointless and more time cosuming.

Comment: @PaulP: Perhaps you don't realize that calling his solution "pointless" comes across as very rude. Please be more careful, we're all only here to help.

Comment: @egrunin I mean pointless in Firebug way in sense that I have tool, which should perform this kind action.

Comment: @Diodeus If I offend you I'm very sorry.

Comment: Huh? Your comment was directed at the OP, not me.